# Using Xtend in a feature based plugin

Tags: xtend

I am trying to learn Xtend and Eclipse plugin development at the same time. I created an Eclipse plugin project and added three Xtend classes to implement Parts in the application model. If I leave the project as a plugin based project and I try to launch it from the product configuration, everything works fine.

However, if I convert it to a feature based project and try to launch it from the product configuration, I get an error trying to resolve `com.google.guava`.

Here is the error log:

```
!SESSION 2018-07-27 06:36:27.121 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.example.e4.rcp.todo.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product com.example.e4.rcp.todo.product -data D:\WiseOldBird\Workspaces\VogellaRcpXtend/runtime-todo.product -dev file:D:/WiseOldBird/Workspaces/VogellaRcpXtend/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/todo.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2018-07-27 06:36:28.434
!MESSAGE Product com.example.e4.rcp.todo.product could not be found.

!ENTRY com.example.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2018-07-27 06:36:28.526
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.example.e4.rcp.todo [75]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.guava


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-27 06:36:28.531
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471)
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\WiseOldBird\Workspaces\VogellaRcpXtend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\todo.product\1532691387713.log.
```

Here is the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Todo
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.e4.rcp.todo;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.e4.rcp.todo
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Require-Bundle: com.google.guava,
 org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib,
 org.eclipse.xtend.lib,
 org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro
```

and here is the feature.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.feature"
      label="Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="com.google.guava"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

I have been unable to figure out how to specify the additional Xtend dependencies in a feature project and need advice.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your product doesn't contain the Guava plugin.
As you want your product to be feature-based you have to add a feature that contains the Guava plugin. If necessary, you can define your own feature for that.